# string parsing in C - string with fomat specifiers

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I'm getting a log file with log data which looks like

```
system%s disconnected: IP%s %s:%s,"1","100.100.100.100","port","1000"
Login by user %s,"TestUserName"
connecting to system%s,"29" 
Newlog by %s on %s,"TestUser2","Wednesday"
```

Which i need to convert to,

```
system1 disconnected: 100.100.100.100 port 1000
Login by user TestUserName
connecting to system29
Newlog by TestUser2 on Wednesday
```

So far i have split this string into 2 strings,  part1 will contain the string with the format specifiers, Part2 with info/data.
for example:

```
1)
part1 = system%s disconnected: IP%s %s:%s
part2 =  "1","100.100.100.100","port","1000"

2) 
part1 = Login by user %s
part2 = "TestUserName"

3)
part1 = connecting to system%s
part2 = "29"
```

I wanted to use sprintf to get the desired output,

```
sprintf(testString,"%s,%s", part1, part2);
printf(testString); //This doesn't work.

printf("system%s disconnected: IP%s %s:%s","1","100.100.100.100","port","1000"); //This works, but not sure of getting here
```

Comment: There is a set of functions related to `printf` whose names begin with `v`, for example `vsprintf`, which are useful if you don't know the number of arguments beforehand.

Comment: If you got only %s (no%i, %d, etc...) you can loop and replace the n %s by the n element in part 2

Comment: Thanks. I may get %i (or) %d as well.

Comment: Then something like a `%[a-Z]` regex pattern combined with a split of part2 on `','` might help you for replacing. There may be functions that already do that as mentionned @ArndtJonasson

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Thanks, I'm trying to find those functions.

Comment: Format specifiers can't be passed as string dynamically with %s. They need to be present at compile time. So please try some compile time MACRO tricks.

Comment: Allow me to prompt you for an MCVE by voting to close...

Comment: @Cid What are you talking about? Format strings aren't regular expressions... Learn C!

Comment: @Sebivor I know they aren't regex, I just suggest to use regex to replace the specifier in the format string by the value it's supposed to have... Learn read !

Comment: @Cid I do not think that word means what you think it means...

Answer (score 0):

I have used strtok to tokenize lines separated by ',' into tokens. I have written very simple function to remove leading and closing apostrophes from strings. The parsing function probably would need to be rewritten to better handle ',' inside strings (try [ao_string_tokenize](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/html_node/libopts_002dao_005fstring_005ftokenize.html)). The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define DBG(...) do;while(0) 
//#define DBG(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
char *remove_leading_and_closing_apostrophe(char *str)
{
    if (str == NULL) 
        return str;
    if (str[0] == '"')
        ++str;
    size_t strleng = strlen(str);
    if (str[strleng - 1] == '"')
        str[strleng - 1] = '\0';
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char line[200];
    const char *args[7];
    size_t argscnt = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
        // remove newline
        assert(line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n');
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';

        DBG("@ read line '%s'\n", line);

        argscnt = 0;
        args[argscnt] = strtok(line, s);
        assert(args[argscnt] != NULL); // not handled correctly
        DBG("@ read arg[%zu]='%s'\n", argscnt, args[argscnt]);
        argscnt++;
        assert(argscnt <= sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]));
        while (args[argscnt-1] != NULL) {
            args[argscnt] = remove_leading_and_closing_apostrophe(strtok(NULL, s));
            DBG("@ read arg[%zu]='%s'\n", argscnt, args[argscnt]);
            argscnt++;
            assert(argscnt <= sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]));
        }
        argscnt--; // incremented one time too much, FIXME

        const char * const * const a = args; // just shorter name
        // This is the most portable way.
        switch(argscnt) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: printf(a[0]); break;
        case 2: printf(a[0],a[1]); break;
        case 3: printf(a[0],a[1],a[2]); break;
        case 4: printf(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]); break;
        case 5: printf(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]); break;
        case 6: printf(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]); break;
        case 7: printf(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]); break;
        default: assert(0); break;
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for the following input on stdin (well formatted, with empty newline on the end):

```
system%s disconnected: IP%s %s:%s,"1","100.100.100.100","port","1000"
Login by user %s,"TestUserName"
connecting to system%s,"29"
Newlog by %s on %s,"TestUser2","Wednesday"
```

produces the following output:

```
system1 disconnected: IP100.100.100.100 port:1000
Login by user TestUserName
connecting to system29
Newlog by TestUser2 on Wednesday
```